# 403 Error : https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm getting errors when trying to send telemetry to application insights.

```
{
"itemsReceived": 2,
"itemsAccepted": 0,
"errors": [{
    "index": 0,
    "statusCode": 403,
    "message": "Component private link id does not match incoming link id and private endpoint connection has restricitve flags enabled"
}, {
    "index": 1,
    "statusCode": 403,
    "message": "Component private link id does not match incoming link id and private endpoint connection has restricitve flags enabled"
}],
"appId": "d7fbb2-f3d-42c-b1b1-f"
```

}

Could someone give me some guidance on what i need to be looking at to resolve that? I'm honestly not sure what the error is telling me.

There is no link id on my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors seem to be coming for incomplete/incorrect "[Azure Private Link for Azure monitor configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/private-link-security)". Please refer to [Review and validate your Private Link Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/private-link-configure#review-and-validate-your-private-link-setup) to ensure that the configuration is done correctly.

Comment: These calls are being made from my public web application. I feel like its a fundamental issue that the request is being sent to a private endpoint. Is this a valid pattern for my website?